# registering a function as callback on flash using creationComplete event fail on linux

Tags: linux, apache-flex, flash, qt, adobe

I have created a flex project on flash builder 4.
In the MXML I have

```
 xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="init();"
```

And to check if it runs

```
<![CDATA[
            private function init():void
            {
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("Submit", submit);
                txtFirstName.text = "fkjkdshf";
                //txtFirstName.text = ExternalInterface.available.toString();
            }
```

I did export release build which creates a SWF file.

When I open the file with Firefox on Windows, It is clear that the event took action -> the text box value changes.

When I open the file on Firefox on LINUX, the text value does not change hence creationComplete event was not performed.

My goal is to set

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("Submit", submit);
```

So that I can call this from a Qt application.

I have checked and the same Flash Player is used on both platforms.

This seems like a bug on Linux Flash Plugin.

How can I overcome this, and register "Submit" ?

Comment: How is this related to Qt (b/c of the tag)?

Comment: Perhaps this is failing on the ExternalInterface.addCallback and you're just not seeing the error, add a trace statement to the init method and use FlashTracer or Vizzy to watch the trace output of the running swf this might lead you closer to the solution, my best off hand guess is it has something to do with case sensitivity in linux vs windows just cause it's the most common error I run into when switching systems for development or deployment.  Also maybe just try changing from submit to some other surely unreserved word like mySpecialSubmit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was as far as I remember in the

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("Submit", submit);
```

The security settings behave differently between Win and Linux. On my Linux platform I had to configure flash to trust the SWF file and the External executable file using '[Global Security Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502)'

note that this tool is quite funky - the flash you see at this page actually control security settings on your computer. Also the 'Always allow' in this tool option didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler should be [applicationComplete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#event%3aapplicationComplete), not creationComplete.

Comment: http://www.wietseveenstra.nl/blog/2007/02/understanding-the-flex-application-startup-event-order/ I don't see any reason (s)he shouldn't be seeing both events being fired and therefore handled although you may be correct in that applicationComplete may be a more appropriate time to make this method call.

Comment: @shaunhusain: Yes, both events would be fired, but I see no guarantee that `ExternalInterface` would be available the way you would expect it to, until the application is actually placed on the stage and all initialization is complete.  I suspect this is the reason for the browsers behaving differently.

Comment: fair enoug,h just wanted to clarify that both events should in fact be firing and that I wasn't missing something here thanks for the clarification agree this could be an issue.